# SELECT QUERY Slows down based on column specified

Tags: sql

I have a simple SELECT statement like this:

```
 SELECT
      COL1,
      COL2,
      COL3
 FROM MYTable
```

If it contains COL3 it slows the query down by 10 minutes. If I remove COL3 from the select list then it takes 5 sec.

Why would adding a column to a select list slow the query down?

Comment: Depends on how big the column is.  If you're trying to return a column that's holding a binary representation of a complete file, for example, then yes, it will be slow.

Comment: the column is a int that hold 0/1

Comment: Another thing to consider:  Is it a derived column or static data?  Without seeing the table structure, we're really just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also post the execution plan for both versions of the query.

Comment: Posting the `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` could help too.

Comment: I think it's possible if for example there is only an index on COL1 that includes only COL2. But this is only true if you are using a WHERE clause.

Comment: If they query is just as you describe above, I'd suspect that this is actually a view, and col3 is a derived column performing some expensive computations, potentially even a `JOIN`, or maybe both.